# Converting Types F#

Tags: .net, types, functional-programming, f#

I have a Discriminated Unions Like this

```
type AbcJson = JsonProvider<"""
{
    "Id": 1234,
    "List": [
          {
            "BT": "abc",
            "Year": 2019,
            "A": 9223372036854775806
          },
          {
            "BT": "bottomUp",
            "Year": 2019
          }
        ]
}
""">

type Event =
    | Cdf of CdfJson.Root
    | Abc of AbcJson.Root
```

I also have a function that returns value from db

```
type g = SqlCommandProvider<"
            Select [BT], [Year], [A] from dbo.Abc;
            " , connectionString>

let dbGet = 
    use cmd = new g(connectionString)
    let data = cmd.Execute() 
    data |> Seq.toArray

let data = dbGet
printfn "%A" data 
// [|{ BT = "abc"; Year = 2019; A = Some 1L };
//   { BT = "abc"; Year = 2019; A = None }|]
```

But when I try to do this

```
let q = Abc(AbcJson.Root(1002, data));
```

I get error like this

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
'JsonProvider‹...>.List []'
but given a 'SqlCommandProvider<...>.Record []'
The type 'JsonProvider‹...>.List' does not match the type 
'SqICommandProvider<...>.Record'
```

I am not able to cast `SqlCommandProvider<...>.Record [] to JsonProvider‹...>.List []`. What can I Do To cast `SqlCommandProvider<...>.Record [] to JsonProvider‹...>.List []`? Some kind of reference or doc will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are retrieving compatible data from two sources -- both a JSON source and a database. However, the JsonProvider and the SqlCommandProviders are generating two different types for storing that data. The JsonProvider creates its own record and the SqlCommandProvider creates its own record. The two different records may have similar members, but you will not be able to "cast" one to the other without copying data from one type to another type.

While you could copy the data from the SqlCommandProvider's record into a JsonProvider's record, I'm not sure that would be the best approach. The F# type providers are really convenient for creating records to match given data. However, in your case, you might consider creating your own record. Something like this...

```
type AbcData {
   string: BT
   int: Year
   long option: A }
```

...into which you store the data from both the JSON source and the database.

You would then copy the data coming from the JsonProvider's record into *your* record type and copy the data coming from the SqlCommandProvider's record into *your* record type. In this way, your record type is the common destination for both JSON and database data.